# 面白かった Vs. 有名だった

Tags: grammar, conjugations, adjectives, tense

So, I'm relatively new to Japanese and I'm learning.
And I notice that some words are paired with かった or だった, even though they're both for referencing past.
So, my question is:  When is it appropriate to use かった and when do you use だった?
I'm sorry if this question is a completely rookie question. :v

Answer (score 3):

The 連用形{れんようけい} ("connecting form") of an *-i* adjective + verbal auxiliary た which indicates the past tense is かった like in 面{おも}白{しろ}かった.

The 連用形{れんようけい} of a *-na* adjective + verbal auxiliary た which indicates past tense is だった like in 有名{ゆうめい}だった.

And The 連用形{れんようけい} of verbal auxiliary だ which means "is" (i.e. it marks the predicate) + verbal auxiliary た which indicates the past tense is だった like in 前{まえ}はその場所{ばしょ}は川{かわ}だった ("In the past, that place was a river").

Comment: なるほど！ So it's completely dependent on whether a word is a na-adjective or a i-adjective.

Comment: I add one case.

Answer (score 3):

**nouns**

だった (was) is the past tense of だ (to be).

卵｛たまご｝だ (it is an egg), 卵｛たまご｝だった (it was an egg).

There are two kinds of adjectives in Japanese the i-adjectives and the na-adjectives.

**i-adjectives**

i-adjectives all end in い. e.g. 面白{おもしろ｝い (to be fun), 楽｛たの｝しい (to be interesting), 速｛はや｝い (to be fast).

To make these adjectives past tense we remove the final い and replace it with かった.

面白｛おもしろ｝かった (was interesting), 楽｛たの｝しかった (was fun), 速｛はや｝かった (was fast).

**na-adjectives**

na-adjectives are those which require な after them when they modify a noun. e.g.　綺麗｛きれい｝ means "clean", but when it is used to modify a noun we have to insert な.

綺麗｛きれい｝な部屋｛へや｝ means "a clean room".
When we want to use these adjectives on their own (i.e. not to modify a noun) then they behave like nouns and we use だった.

部屋｛へや｝は綺麗｛きれい｝だった (the room was clean)

Note that just because an adjective ends in い it is not necessarily an i-adjective. Most are, but there are some exceptions like きれい in this example.

Comment: Yeah I learned this, apparently a good way to tell whether or not something is an i-adjective or not even if it ends in い is to write it in kanji for convenience, since an i-adjective will have to be punctuated with the い kana, yes?

Comment: That's right. An i-adjective must have い in hiragana at the end.

Comment: @Touky But you should be careful with false positives like 幸い（さいわい）.